# AWS CodeCommit - deny push when there are differences in a specific path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

**Question**

Is there a way to deny users modify specific paths in an AWS CodeCommit repository? For instance, if a user modifies a file in a path `read/only/path`, IAM policy denies the git push.

**Context**

We're using a monorepo in your project and we want developers to be able to see all codes and patterns we use. However, some developers are not allowed to make changes in certain pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

IAM does provide the ability for you to generate policies that prevent writes to specific branches, paths, and files within a repo.

To deny write access to a directory you’ll add a `DENY` effect on the `PutFile` action, and then specify the `filePath` that you want to deny write for.

There are other required attributes for the `PutFile` action, and you can read more about them in the [AWS PutFile Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_PutFile.html), and more generally about [IAM with CodeCommit here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscodecommit.html).

Comment: thank you for your reply. How can I create such a policy? Should I specify `filePath` at IAM conditions?

Comment: In the AWS IAM console, select policies from the menu options on the left, create a valid policy as per the AWS documentation, and then attach that policy to the IAM User.

Comment: Yes, but how do I write the policy? Something like that? {
 Effect: 'Deny',
 Action: 'codecommit:PutFile',
 Resource: 'arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:*:REPOSITORY',
 Condition: {
  StringEquals: {
   filePath: 'MY_FILE_PATH',
  },
 },
};

Comment: This tutorial should help you; its specific to merges and pushes to repos and branches, but you can follow the same pattern and use the info you learnt in the links in my answer to craft the exact policy you need. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-conditional-branch.html